# How to send form submitted data to paypal in Drupal?

Tags: drupal, paypal, integration, paypal-sandbox

I need to implement paypal integration with webform

so I have installed webform and webform_paypal modules

but my question is filling all form information, by clicking on button I should redirect to paypal with form details entered

I have set button from backend button -"paypal button" and of type "Buynow"

But I get an error

```
   "Some required information is missing or incomplete. Please correct your entries and try again."
```

so how can i set form data and merchant details from paypal module ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What's the information you *are* sending?

Comment: how to send and where to send is not known as it is in module webform_paypal

Comment: We'll need much more information than this, unfortunately. Please find the code that generates the <form> and include it in your question. Thanks! :)